# Prevent windows shortcuts from automatically updating when file is moved

Tags: windows-7

Creating a shortcut to a file in Windows 7, the short-cut automatically searches for the new file location if the file is later moved, and updates the shortcut. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why do you want to? Do you like have broken shortcuts? ;)

Comment: "Do you like have broken shortcuts?". Yes! Shortcuts should become broken when a file is moved, as this indicates the file is obsolete and not to be used.